# How to overlap different DIV ID's

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

Wasn't sure how to word the title so here it goes.

[image: My attempt]

I'm wanting to move the tables so the headings are on the blue part of my page, but the body of the table is still on the grey. I tried just `margin-bottom:-50px;` and as expected was the above result. Below in the css and html code of my attemot so far!

How do I this?

Blue section:

```
#section2 {
    background-color: #2aa3ef; /**blue**/
    padding-top:80px;
    padding-bottom:80px;
}
```

Grey section:

```
#section1 {
    background-color: #e6ecf0;
    padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; /**bluey white**/
}

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">        
    <table class="points_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><h4>Premium domains</h4></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="points_table_scrollbar">
            <tr class="odd">
                <td class="col-xs-7">Bidder.co.uk</td>
                <td class="col-xs-3">24hr</td>
                <td class="col-xs-3">£200</td>
                <td class="col-xs-12"><a class="btn btn-warning" href="#">button</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="even">
                <td class="col-xs-1">2</td>
                <td class="col-xs-7">Test Points 2</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">10</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">0</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">5</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="odd">
                <td class="col-xs-1">3</td>
                <td class="col-xs-7">Test Points 3</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">10</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">0</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">5</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="even">
                <td class="col-xs-1">4</td>
                <td class="col-xs-7">Test Points 4</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">10</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">0</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">5</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="odd">
                <td class="col-xs-1">5</td>
                <td class="col-xs-7">Test Points 5</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">10</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">0</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">5</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="even">
                <td class="col-xs-1">6</td>
                <td class="col-xs-7">Test Points 6</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">10</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">0</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">5</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="odd">
                <td class="col-xs-1">7</td>
                <td class="col-xs-7">Test Points 7</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">10</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">0</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">5</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="even">
                <td class="col-xs-1">8</td>
                <td class="col-xs-7">Test Points 8</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">10</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">0</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">5</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="odd">
                <td class="col-xs-1">9</td>
                <td class="col-xs-7">Test Points 9</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">10</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">0</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">5</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="even">
                <td class="col-xs-1">10</td>
                <td class="col-xs-7">Test Points 10</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">10</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">0</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">5</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="odd">
                <td class="col-xs-1">11</td>
                <td class="col-xs-7">Test Points 11</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">10</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">0</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">5</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="even">
                <td class="col-xs-1">12</td>
                <td class="col-xs-7">Test Points 12</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">10</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">0</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">5</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="odd">
                <td class="col-xs-1">13</td>
                <td class="col-xs-7">Test Points 13</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">10</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">0</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">5</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="even">
                <td class="col-xs-1">14</td>
                <td class="col-xs-7">Test Points 14</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">10</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">0</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">5</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="odd">
                <td class="col-xs-1">15</td>
                <td class="col-xs-7">Test Points 15</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">10</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">0</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">5</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="even">
                <td class="col-xs-1">16</td>
                <td class="col-xs-7">Test Points 16</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">10</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">0</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">5</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="odd">
                <td class="col-xs-1">17</td>
                <td class="col-xs-7">Test Points 17</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">10</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">0</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">5</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="even">
                <td class="col-xs-1">18</td>
                <td class="col-xs-7">Test Points 18</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">10</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">0</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">5</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="odd">
                <td class="col-xs-1">19</td>
                <td class="col-xs-7">Test Points 19</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">10</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">0</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">5</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="even">
                <td class="col-xs-1">20</td>
                <td class="col-xs-7">Test Points 20</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">10</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">0</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">5</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">1</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Could you give your HTML also.

Comment: you need to add position relative to table and z-index

Comment: @klooven - done :)

Comment: @AndréDion, that was a typo - with px it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
#section1 {
    background-color: #e6ecf0;
    padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:20px; /**bluey white**/
    position:relative;
}
```

and give to

```
.points_table{
  top:-50px;
position:absolute;
}
```

top value as per your table head gone upper side